# Apple Script that copies/pastes text is broken in Yosemite

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, osx-yosemite

I made a simple AppleScript that copies the layer names from Photoshop and pastes them into Illustrator. It worked fine in Mountain Lion but now it doesn't work properly in Yosemite. It repeats 6 times, but it doesn't seem to activate Illustrator on the first run through. It does activate Illustrator the other 5 times it repeats. Here it is:

```
repeat 6 times
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2014" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Photoshop"
        keystroke "/" using command down
        keystroke "c" using command down
        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Illustrator"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke return
        keystroke "-"
        keystroke space
    end tell
end tell
end repeat
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events" to repeat 6 times

    tell process "Photoshop" to repeat until frontmost is true
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
    end repeat
    keystroke "/" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down
    keystroke tab

    tell process "Illustrator" to repeat until frontmost is true
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
    end repeat
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke return
    keystroke "-"
    keystroke space

end repeat
```